# Problem with reading a .csv file into a Verilog module

Tags: verilog, testbench

I was trying to read a .csv file and use its contents. The csv is formatted as:

```
0001,1010,1110
0101,1100,1001
```

My code is:

```
`timescale 1 ns/10 ps  

module tb;
    
    reg a, b;
   
    reg[3:0] r1;
    reg[3:0] r2;
    reg[3:0] r3;

    integer i, f, j;

    initial
    begin 
        
        f = $fopen("vec.csv", "r");
        
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i = i +1)
        //while(! $feof(f))
        begin
        
            j = $fscanf(f,"%b %b %b",r1,r2,r3);
          
            #20;  
        end
        $display("%b,%b,%b", r1, r2, r3);

        $fclose(f);
        $display("pass");
    end
endmodule
```

The output is:

```
0001,xxxx,xxxx                                                                                                 
0001,xxxx,xxxx                                                                                                 
pass
```

It seems that it can't read anything besides the first 4 bits of the 1st line. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try inserting commas `,`

```
      j = $fscanf(f,"%b,%b,%b",r1,r2,r3);
```

Comment: Thanks, what if there was 20 or more sets of 4 bits in every row? should I keep writing %b,%b,%b,.... for 20 times. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is almost a completely new question. 

If you know exactly how many values are on each line, you can use `$fscanf` to read one value at a time in a loop. Otherwise you can read one line at a time using `$fgets` and then split the line into an array of values. This would be much easier to do in SystemVerilog using a package like [SVlib](https://www.verilab.com/resources/svlib/).